# Facebook sdk for js vs passport-facebook login system

Tags: node.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, passport-facebook

I am working on a website and I need a facebook login system for users. Since I am working with NodeJs I found the passport module for authentication. I also know that facebook provides their own javscript sdk to simply login users directly from the client side.

**My question is: what is the difference between these two ways of authenticating users? (using the facebook js sdk on the client side and using passport facebook strategy on the server-side)**